# How do I get toLocaleTimeString() to work for a timezone that isn't mine?

Tags: reactjs, methods, kotlin-js

I am using KotlinJS and react, and I have been trying to make a time widget, but I cannot display anything other than est (my time zone) with the toLocaleTimeString() method

```
import csstype.FontWeight
import csstype.px
import emotion.react.css
import kotlinx.browser.window
import kotlinx.js.timers.setInterval
import org.w3c.xhr.XMLHttpRequest
import react.FC
import react.Props
import react.dom.html.ReactHTML.div
import react.dom.html.ReactHTML.time
import react.useEffect
import react.useState
import kotlin.js.Date

interface ClockWidget : Widget {
    var city: String
    var continent: String
}


val clockWidgetComponent = FC<ClockWidget> { props ->
    var currentTime by useState("")
    val city by useState(props.city)
    val continent by useState(props.continent)
    var difference by useState("")
//    var clockResponse: dynamic =
//        JSON.parse(httpGet("https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/${continent}/${city}"))
    div {
        css {
            fontWeight = FontWeight.bold
            fontSize = 32.px
            lineHeight = 39.px
        }
//      var options = JSON.parse<dynamic>("""{ "timeZone": "${props.continent}/${city}" }""")
        + Date().toLocaleTimeString()
    }


    useEffect {
//        currentTime = clockResponse.datetime.toString()
    }

}
```

`+Date().toLocaleTimeString()`

this is where i am trying to display the time, but using "PST", or "EST" as the parameter for the method above ^ always displays the same as "en-US"

I tried using the js() method and using js code, but it must be a continuous String, and that wont work for me because I need to insert variables. I also cannot use API because the get request slows down the rest of the page until it is finished.